# How to add the custom attributes value from xml element in c# using linq?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, linq, linq-to-xml

Hi i have a xml document

```
<task>
<directory path="C:\Backup\"/>
<days value="2" />
</task>
```

I want to get the path of the directory and the days value from this in c# using linq how can i achieve this?

```
The output should be 
C:\Backup\ and 2
```

I have so far tried something like below the xdocument is the path to my xml file which works fine

```
              var directory = xdocument.Descendants("task")
                              .Elements("directory")
                              .Attributes("path");
```

but this part is not working. Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var directory = xdoc.DescendantsAndSelf("task") 
                  .Select(c => new 
                  {
                    Path = c.Elements("directory").Attributes("path").First().Value,
                    Day = c.Elements("days").Attributes("value").First().Value,
                  });
```

or if you want you one string:

```
var directory = xdoc.DescendantsAndSelf("task") 
                  .Select(c => new 
                  {
                    Complete = c.Elements("directory").Attributes("path").First().Value +
                    c.Elements("days").Attributes("value").First().Value
                  });
```

**EDIT**
you could the iterate through them like this:

```
foreach(var item in directory)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Path+ " + item.Day);
}
```

Comment: thanks but it did not work i was thinking if it works i will split them in to seperate strings.

Comment: @nzdev the top example does that

Comment: @nzdev I have edited my answer to include how to use `directory`.

Comment: add this `using System.Xml.Linq` to you class

Comment: I have got this already i dont why it doesn't recognize this so strange anyway thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

check this,because `Descendants()` and `Elements()` return `IEnumerable` results

```
var directory = xdocument.Descendants("task").First().
                              .Elements("directory").First().
                              .Attribute("path").Value;
```